# Importing full test plans into Azure DevOps from .xls

Tags: azure-devops, import, ado, xls, test-plan

I’m trying to import a full test plan from a .xls file into ADO. This test plan is made up of a few parent test suites, each with their own child test suites within them and then of course the test cases. Does anyone know if this is possible? Or can .xls imports only be done at the test suite level?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Microsoft Excel to bulk import Test Plans, Test Suites and Test Cases into the project in Azure DevOps organization (ADO org):

1. Ensure you have installed the extension "[**Azure DevOps Open in Excel**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=blueprint.vsts-open-work-items-in-excel)" to your ADO org where you want to import the test items to.
2. Ensure you have installed **Visual Studio** (2017 or later) and the [**Azure DevOps Office Integration 2019**](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#other-family) plug-in on your machine.
3. In the target project of your ADO org, create a work item query to filter some items. Then select option "**`Open in Excel`**".

   [image]
4. Copy all the test items you want to import into the Excel worksheet opened by Azure DevOps.
5. On the opening Excel worksheet, select **Team** ribbon > **Publish** option to publish the items from worksheet to Azure DevOps.

For more details, you can reference the documentation "[**Add or modify work items in bulk with Microsoft Excel**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process)".

---

Comment: @domenicqatest, is there any update from you? Have you tried the steps shared in my above answer to use Microsoft Excel to bulk import Test Plans, Test Suites and Test Cases into the project in Azure DevOps organization? Does the method work for you?